# Django forms selecting data based on request user

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am developing a django application which has a form for creating ingredients. The form contains a dropdown for selecting Recipes. When a user creates an ingredient, in the dropdown, I want that only those recipes should appear that are created by the same user.

Here is my code:

```
#forms.py
class IngredientForm(forms.ModelForm):
    primal = forms.BooleanField()
    class Meta:
        model = Ingredient
        fields = ('recipe_id', 'title', 'instructions', 'rules')
#models.py
class Recipe(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=500)
    rules = models.TextField(max_length=500,blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
            return self.title
class Ingredient(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    recipe_id = models.ForeignKey(Recipe, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    instructions = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    rules = models.TextField(max_length=500,blank=True)
    primal = models.CharField(default='0',max_length=500,blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
            return self.title

#views.py

def create_ingredient(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
           form = IngredientForm(request.POST)
           if form.is_valid():
               current_user = request.user
               data = form.cleaned_data
               ingredient_data=Ingredient.objects.create(user=current_user, recipe_id=data['recipe_id'],title=data['title'], primal=data['primal'], instructions=data['instructions'], rules=data['rules'])
               ingredient_data.save()
               ingredient = Ingredient.objects.get(pk = ingredient_data.pk)
               return redirect('ingredient_detail', pk=ingredient.pk)
           else:
               messages.error(request, "Error")
    return render(request, 'create_ingredient.html', {'form': IngredientForm })
```

The problem is that right now, when the user tries to select a recipe, the recipes created by all users of the site appear in the 'recipe_id' dropdown. He should only be able to see recipes in the dropdown that are created by himself. Any ideas how to do it?

UPDATE FROM ANSWER:

If I use this:

```
...
    if request.method == 'POST':
           form = IngredientForm(current_user=request.user, request.POST)
           if form.is_valid():
...
```

it gives me this syntax error: `non-keyword arg after keyword arg` in this line `form = IngredientForm(current_user=request.user, request.POST)`

UPDATE#2:

If I use:

```
...
    if request.method == 'POST':
           form = IngredientForm( request.POST,current_user=request.user)
           if form.is_valid():
...
```

It gives me error: `__init__() got multiple values of argument 'current.user'`

If I use:

```
...
    if request.method == 'POST':
           form = IngredientForm( request.POST)
           if form.is_valid():
...
```

It gives me error: `'QueryDict' object has no attribute 'id'`

UPDATE # 3:

After implementing the latest update from answer. It gives me error `name 'current_user' is not defined` 
in the following piece of code:

```
def create_ingredient(request):
    form = IngredientForm(current_user=request.user)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the model form you can do this:

```
class IngredientForm(ModelForm):
    primal = forms.BooleanField()
    class Meta:
        model = Ingredient
        fields = ('recipe_id', 'title', 'instructions', 'rules')

    def __init__(self, current_user, *args, **kwargs):
        super(IngredientForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['recipe_id'].queryset = self.fields['recipe_id'].queryset.filter(user=current_user.id)
```

then instantiate the form like so

```
form = IngredientForm(current_user=request.user)
```

EDIT #1:

Passing in the user to the POST request form:

```
if request.method == "POST":
    form = IngredientForm(request.POST, current_user=request.user)
    if form.is_valid():
        ....
```

EDIT #2:

Try changing the init decleration to what is below and pop the user from the kwargs:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    current_user = kwargs.pop('current_user', None)
    super(IngredientForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    if current_user:
        self.fields['recipe_id'].queryset = self.fields['recipe_id'].queryset.filter(user=current_user.id)
```

I think this might solve your problems, leave the rest of the code the same as my answer above (where you create the forms)

Comment: Do i have to use it in views.py: form = IngredientForm(current_user=request.user)  right?

Comment: correct.  Where you have the line `return render(request, 'create_ingredient.html', {'form': IngredientForm })` replace `IngredientForm` with the instantiated form that took the request.user as an argument

Comment: Thanks @nkhumphreys it worked but there is one problem. When I submit the form, it gives error in the following segment:  form = IngredientForm(request.POST)
           if form.is_valid(): .... If you can solve this error, I will mark the answer as correct UPDATE: The error it gives me is IngredientForm object is not callable

Comment: That is because you will need to pass the user into every where the form class is instantiated.  You have added the keyword argument to the constructor so it always has to be there.

Comment: Can you give me example how can I modify the error giving segment, sorry I am a newbie

Comment: I tried to use this: form = form(current_user=request.user,request.POST) in my POST segment, but it doesnt accept it

Comment: Please update your question with the error you are seeing.  I can not help with the current information unfortunately

Comment: OK, this was just me typing too fast and getting the arguments the wrong way round.  Python was telling you exactly what the error was, the keyword arguments have to come last in a method call in python.  I have updated my answer to switch the arguments to __init__

Comment: Added a second edit, i made a mistake in the first \_\_init__ decleration, current user was not a kwarg but I was treating it as one, I just had a look at some old code I had written

Comment: I made third edit to the question, it gives another error now

Comment: Did you copy and paste my code directly?  There is an error on the first line of the init method.  I assigned it to a variable called user instead of current user, just change that.  Updated

Comment: Oh sorry, I didnt notice that. But It works now! @nkhumphreys you are awesome!